# Using Relational Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, relational-database

I have three tables Business, Users, and Subscriptions. The goal is to be able get the business' names associated with the user. The result should be an array of business names that the user has signed up for in subscriptions

List of Tables

```
Schema |       Name        | Type  |
--------+-------------------+-------
 public | businesses        | table 
 public | subscriptions     | table 
 public | users             | table
```

---

Businesses Table

```
  Column   |            Type                                                        
------------+-----------------------------
 id         | integer                      
 name       | character varying(255)       
 created_at | timestamp without time zone  
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone
```

Business Model

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

---

Subscriptions Table

```
   Column    |            Type                                   
-------------+-----------------------------
 id          | integer                     
 user_id     | integer                      
 business_id | integer                      
 created_at  | timestamp without time zone  
 updated_at  | timestamp without time zone
```

Subscription Model

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :business
end
```

---

Users Table

```
     Column      |            Type                                   
-----------------+-----------------------------
 id              | integer                 
 username        | character varying(255)       
 password_digest | character varying(255)       
 email           | character varying(255)       
 created_at      | timestamp without time zone  
 updated_at      | timestamp without time zone
```

User Model

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_secure_password
       has_many :subscriptions
    end
```

---

Rails Console

```
 u = User.find(1)
 u.subscriptions.businesses.name

 Response: undefined method `business'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing an additional query for every single Subscription (as in Alireza's answer), you can do this with just one query using Rails' built-in [`includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) method:

```
subscriptions = u.subscriptions.includes(:business)
```

This will return a relation for all of the Subscriptions including their associated Businesses. Now you can get the business' names without doing an additional query:

```
business_names = subscriptions.map {|sub| sub.business.name }
```

I *think* you can also do this in one step using [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck):

```
business_names = u.subscriptions.includes(:business).pluck("businesses.name")
```

I'm not certain `pluck` plays nice with `includes`, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I got this error Association named &#39;subscriptions&#39; was not found on Subscription; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: @user3882976 Sorry about that, I think it should be `includes(:business)` instead of `includes(:subscriptions => :business)`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

since User has many Subscriptions, the call to `u.subscriptions` returns an array of Subscriptions, therefore you need to loop through the array and call the `business` association on each record. you can achieve what you need using:

```
business_names = u.subscriptions.map {|subscription| subscription.business.name }
```

Comment: Except this will do one query for every subscription—if there are 100 subscriptions you'll end up doing 100+ queries. Not a great solution.

Comment: @Jordan This only answers what the OP asked, of course it can be optimized in many ways, but that's not what the OP is asking. I could post 10 ways to achieve the same thing using `joins` and `includes`.

Comment: I didn't say it was a wrong answer, I said it wasn't a great answer. If you "could post 10 ways to achieve the same thing" then it's not clear to my why you chose one of the worst.

Comment: Because my answer is meant to show why OP's existing line of code to retrieve the records is not working, with an explaination and correcting his mistake. You are welcome to post answers showing him how to do it better. Sometimes we just want to know what we are doing wrong so we can learn, and we are not looking for alternative or better solutions